# c# [NonSerialized] field with inline initialization isn't initialized after deserialization

Tags: c#, serialization, initialization

I have a [Nonserialized] field in my class that is initialized inline:

```
[NonSerialized]
private bool running = true;
```

However, after deserializing an object I have running == false. This is not what I want. Can I force inline initializatin to work for all [NonSerialized] fields? Otherwise I will have to implement ISerializable...

Comment: This happens because the deserialization process creates a new uninitialized object of your type without calling any constructors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<del>You could set it in the default constructor.</del>

Implement the System.Runtime.Serialization.IDeserializationCallback

It is called afther the object is deserialized so you can perform your extra initialization there .

Comment: Does not work. As far as I understand, a class with [Serializable] attribute implicitly implements a constructor with a special signature that is called on deserialization.

Comment: Ok, try the other solution :)

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the thing I was looking for!